# How to Authenticate to Azure Active Directory Graph API on a Users behalf?

Tags: api, azure, office365

I have setup an AD in Windows Azure and created some users as well. I have also registered/created an application inside AD for third party application to access API(using Client and Secret ID).

I have followed the steps listed in the below links for authenticating to Graph API :

[Authenticating to the Graph API](http://community.office365.com/en-us/blogs/office_365_community_blog/archive/2013/06/17/authenticating-to-the-graph-api.aspx)

[Getting an Application ID and Password for Authenticating to the Graph API](http://community.office365.com/en-us/blogs/office_365_community_blog/archive/2013/06/25/getting-an-application-id-and-password-for-authenticating-to-the-graph-api.aspx)

But when i tried with my client and Secret ID i am getting "Invalid Client error" message .

```
Error validating credentials. Invalid client secret is provided.
```

Also is it possible to Authenticate to Graph API on a Users behalf (By providing Client Credentials of a User inside AD).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are you using as client and secret ID?

Comment: i have solved the problem, issue is i have to encode request body. But after authenticating on users behalf by providing credentials to windows login page (oauth 2 flow) how come i know that which user is logged in. Does Oauth2 token response contains any information about a logged in user or is there any API available for getting current logged in user.Plz help.

Answer (score 0):

The response from Azure ActiveDirectory will contain an id_token that contains the user's email in the UPN field. If you use the ADAL library or the libraries from Office 365 API tools http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2014/03/12/announcing-office-365-api-tools-for-visual-studio-preview.aspx, this information is available in the object model.